# PostbackUrl and Query String Parameter

Tags: asp.net, postbackurl

Scratching my head about this. In the rendered HTML for the code below, the btnEdit (in the GridView) has the correct Javascript in the onclick parameter (onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBack..."). The btnAddNew has no onclick handler at all. Why?
There is no compilation or runtime error, and the page uses a master page that has the Form tag..

```
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddNew" SkinID="btnAddNew" runat="server" 
    PostBackUrl='<%# "EditUser.aspx?action="+Constants.actionAdd %>' /> 
<asp:GridView ID="UserGridView" 
      runat="server" 
      DataKeyNames="UserId" 
      >  
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:ImageButton id="btnEdit" SkinID="btnEdit" runat="server" 
                    PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("UserId", "EditUser.aspx?
                     action="+Constants.actionEdit+"&uid={0}") %>' />
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                        
      </Columns>          
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Check if the PostBackUrl makes its way to the rendered page intact.  If so, then the asp:ImageButton control does not have a PostBackUrl property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like you don't need data binding tag (<%#) for the btnAddNew button. So you can assign this property at server side :

```
btnAddNew.PostBackUrl = "EditUser.aspx?action=" + Constants.actionAdd;
```

Comment: Thanks, works of course. Not only do I not need the data binding evaluator tag, but I cannot use it on an item that it is not data-bound. Duh!